# WPFにおける階層構造を持ったViewModelに対するデータバインディングの仕組み

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPFのデータバインディングについて、特に階層構造を持つViewModelをバインドする場合の仕組みについて教えて下さい。

ViewModel定義

```
public class Outer : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Inner Inner { /* get,setのコードは省略 */ }
}

public class Inner : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string Hoge { /* get,setのコードは省略 */ }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:Outer/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Inner.Hoge}"/>
</Grid>
```

上記のようなコードであるとき、`TextBox`は`Inner`インスタンスの`PropertyChanged`イベントを直接的に監視しているのでしょうか？
それとも`DataContext`で指定されている`Outer`インスタンスの`PropertyChanged`イベントを監視しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際に`Outer`と`Inner`の`PropertyChanged`へイベントハンドラを追加して検証しました。

```
public class Outer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Outer()
    {
        // _innerはInnerプロパティ内で参照するprivateメンバ
        _inner = new Inner();
        _inner.PropertyChanged +=new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_inner_PropertyChanged);
        this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Outer_PropertyChanged);
    }
    private void _inner_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner: " + e.PropertyName);
    }
    private void Outer_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Outer: " + e.PropertyName);
    }
    //...
}
```

ここで`Inner.Hoge`の値を変更してみますと`Inner`側しか発火していませんでした。`TextBox`の表示は正しく更新されました。(素直に実装すれば`Outer`の`PropertyChanged`は`Inner`自体を変更しないと発火しないようになると考えます。)

よって、`TextBox`の更新に関係しているのは`Inner`側の`PropertyChanged`だと考えました。

Comment: 質問が分かりにくいようでしたら申し訳ないです。ご指摘の挙動は理解していて、そこは問題ではありません。頂いたコードを使って例示するのであれば、 "{Binding Inner.Hoge}" の記述で実行される"TextBoxの"イベントハンドラメソッドは、_inner_PropertyChangedなのか、Outer_PropertyChangedなのか、ということです。

Comment: 言葉が曖昧で申し訳ありません。この例ですと、`Inner.Hoge`の変更に際し、`_inner_PropertyChanged`のみが実行されました。

Comment: お手数おかけしました。ありがとうございます。確かにこの挙動を見る限り、InnerのPropertyChangedイベントが監視されていると解釈するのが良さそうですね。

Comment: 実際のところ、監視というよりも`Text`プロパティと`Inner.Hoge`がバインディングオブジェクトによって接続されているとみなすのが適当ですが、あまり気にしなくても良いのかもしれません。また、`Outer`のメソッドで`Inner.Hoge`を変更して`Outer`側で検出して`PropertyChanged`させるような実装も可能ですが、ここではそういった特殊なケースは仮定しませんでした。お役に立てれば幸いです。